# Unable to assign QString to QQuickItem* with Qt.resolvedUrl

Tags: application-development, qml, ubuntu-sdk

I have the following code:

```
Tabs {
    Tab {
        id: financialDetailsTab
        title: i18n.tr("Financial Details")
        page: Qt.resolvedUrl("FinancialDetails.qml")
    }
    Tab {
        id: monthlyBudgetTab
        title: i18n.tr("Monthly Budget")
        page: Qt.resolvedUrl("MonthlyBudget.qml")
    }
    Tab {
        id: annualBudgetTab
        title: i18n.tr("Annual Budget")
        page: Qt.resolvedUrl("AnnualBudget.qml")
    }
    Tab {
        id: savingsGoalsTab
        title: i18n.tr("Savings Goals")
        page: Qt.resolvedUrl("SavingsGoals.qml")
    }
}
```

which is generating the following errors:

```
Unable to assign QString to QQuickItem*
Unable to assign QString to QQuickItem*
Unable to assign QString to QQuickItem*
Unable to assign QString to QQuickItem*
```

on the lines where `Qt::resolvedUrl` is being used. The `Tabs` component is a part of the Ubuntu SDK, and not Qt Quick, and the only [example](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/ubuntu-12.10/qml/mobile/qml-ubuntu-components0-tabs.html) of it's use doesn't provide much insight into the problem.

I've added the exact same lines as properties of the `MainView`, outside of the `Tabs` component, and the problem has not been evident there, leading me to believe the issue lies with the Ubuntu component.

All the files exist and sit at the same level in the project as this one. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I don't know what you mean, with "I've added the exact same lines as properties of the MainView, outside of the Tabs component"... and that it was without a problem. Don't know what you wrote exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way of writing this is:

```
Tabs {
  Tab {
    page: FinancialDetails {}
    // ...
  }
  // ...
}
```

`page` wants an `Item`, but `Qt.resolvedUrl` returns a string. Which won't be interpreted as a URL to an Item and it therefore won't be loaded.